# Mapping the clusters of two files based on two columns

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have two files. First file has three columns: SiteID , Time and ClusterNo.

Second File has four columns : SiteA_ID, SiteB_ID, Time and ClusterNo.

```
file1 <- data.frame("Site_ID" = sample(74000:74500, 1000, replace =TRUE), "Time" =  runif(1000)*100, "ClusterNo." = sample(1:500, 1000, replace = TRUE)) 
file2 <- data.frame("SiteA_ID" = sample(74000:74500, 1000, replace =TRUE),"SiteB_ID" = sample(74000:74500, 1000, replace =TRUE), "Time" =     runif(1000)*100, "ClusterNo." = sample(1:500, 1000, replace = TRUE))
```

We have to find out which clusters(of file1 and file2) are mapping in a way that Site_ID of file1 is matching with either Site(A or B) of file2; and time of file1 and that of file2 is having difference not more than 2 units.

Desired output is a file containing three columns : ClusterNoOfFile1 and ClusterNoOfFile2 and CommonSite

[Note: CommonSite is the common site of file1 and file2 for which clusters are mapping]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an approach to accomplish something along the lines of what you are going for (it is not very clear to me what your output should be given your input). You may be able to modify it based on what you specifically need.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Generate the data (your code)
file1 <- data.frame("Site_ID" = sample(74000:74500, 1000, replace =TRUE), "Time" =  runif(1000)*100, "ClusterNo." = sample(1:500, 1000, replace = TRUE))
file2 <- data.frame("SiteA_ID" = sample(74000:74500, 1000, replace =TRUE),"SiteB_ID" = sample(74000:74500, 1000, replace =TRUE), "Time" =     runif(1000)*100, "ClusterNo." = sample(1:500, 1000, replace = TRUE))

# Convert file2 to long format so there is only one site id
file2Long <- gather(file2, Site_Type, Site_ID, -Time, -ClusterNo.)

# Inner join with file1 so you retain all rows with matching site id.
file12 <- inner_join(file1, file2Long, by = 'Site_ID')

# Compute time difference and store whether it is within range
file12$TimeDiff2 <- abs(file12$Time.x - file12$Time.y) <= 2

# Filter the ones that meet the threshold criteria of 2, and retain only
# columns of interest.
file12Diff2 <- filter(file12, TimeDiff2 == TRUE)
file12Diff2 <- select(file12Diff2, ClusterNo..x, ClusterNo..y, Site_ID)
```

Output will look like this (.x mens file1 and .y means file2 - you can change those names to whatever you need them to be):

```
  ClusterNo..x ClusterNo..y Site_ID
1          400           96   74308
2          298          438   74027
3          397          137   74265
4          420          286   74395
5          280           77   74097
6          176          333   74303
```